# PTIJ: How are we supposed to ever be bisimcha?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Dovid HaMelech tells us in Tehillim (100:2) "עבדו את ה' בשמחה", that we should serve Hashem with happiness. Yet the Mishnah in Taanis (4:6) says "מִשֶּׁנִּכְנַס אָב, מְמַעֲטִין בְּשִׂמְחָה" that when the Father enters we should reduce our happiness. Pashut pshat, the father being referred to in the mishnah is Hashem being that the mishnah doesn't specify whose father, and the only father who would apply to everyone is Hashem. As the famous Uncle Moishy song goes, "Hashem is here, Hashem is there, Hashem is truly everywhere". Being that Hashem is truly everywhere at all times, how are we ever supposed to fullfill עבדו את ה' בשמחה if we're always in a situation of needing to reduce the simcha?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Depends אם כבנים אם כעבדים

Comment: I love that you brought a ראייה from משה דודנו

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Hashem is here, Hashem is there, Hashem is truly everywhere, משנכנס אב can't be referring to Hashem, as he is there already.